# C Language - Type assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers, struct, variable-assignment

I'm having problems with this Pointer List:

```
struct list{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct list *next_ptr;
};
```

I have this function that sadly crashes every time and the cause might be this type assignment fail.

```
boolean funzione_esame(struct list **ptrptr, int *number){
    if(*ptrptr != NULL){
    struct list *tmp;
    struct list *pos;
    pos=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    pos=&((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);
    *number=1;
    while(pos != NULL){
        if(pos->x <= (*ptrptr)->y){
            pos->x=(*ptrptr)->y;
            if(pos->x >= pos->y){
                tmp=pos;
                pos=&(pos->next_ptr);
                free(tmp);
                continue;
            }
        }
        pos=&(pos->next_ptr);
        ptrptr=&((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);
        *number=*number + 1;
        }
    return TRUE;
    } else return FALSE;
}
```

Warning is at this lines:

- `pos=&((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);`
- `pos=&(pos->next_ptr);`

I don't know what I did wrong because the pointer type it's always the same (`struct list`).
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: um, do you mind formatting your code a bit?

Comment: Anytime you have `ptrvar = allocation_func(...);` followed immediately by `ptrvar = something else;` put a giant red-flag in your code, because at *best* you just coded a bodacious memory leak. And both of those warnings are correct (and should be errors if you're compiling pedantically). The types do not match. Finally, *what is your code supposed to be doing?*

Comment: Your *pos* variable is the same type as *next_ptr*, it is struct list*, you don't need & when assigning *pos->next_ptr* to *pos*. Please, format your code, there can be more problems and nobody is going to dive into you poorly formatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of your problem [*Type assignment from incompatible pointer type*] is

```
pos=&((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);
```

Change to

```
pos= (*ptrptr)->next_ptr;
```

`pos` is a `struct list *`, so is `(*ptrptr)->next_ptr`.

Same goes for `pos=&(pos->next_ptr);`, change to `pos= pos->next_ptr;`

Also, the previous `malloc()` is not necessary. You're immediately assigning some other pointer to `pos` thereby the previously allocated memory is not being used, neither being `free`d, creating memory leak.

Comment: Those are the lines you got warnings for. Warnings - there for a reason. For historical reasons C is a little too ready to let you shoot your foot off.

Comment: Thanks now it worked ^^ 
Still it appears another problem. The function should trasform this list (where the list is in this format (x,y):
(1,2), (3,6), (4,8), (5,7), (6,9)

To this:
(1,2), (3,6), (6,8), (8,9)

Till (6,8) it works but when the second if log in ( if(pos->x >= pos->y) ) it doesn't work properly. Cause when I stamp the final list last element is (3615464,3615312) and not (8,9). There must be an error in the function but I can't figure it out.